# Django QuerySet - Memory usage / Laziness

Tags: python, django, memory, lazy-evaluation, django-queryset

I have a django model which has a load of relatively small fields and then one kinda huge one.  Let's say something like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

thing = models.ForeignKey('Thing')
egg = models.TextField()
spoon = models.TextField()
race = models.FloatField()
big_field = models.TextField()
```

big_field is only needed in a small number of functions, however the model is used all over the place.  How can I avoid big_field being stored in memory?  Is this what lazy evaluation is doing?  Say I iterated over a QuerySet extracting egg each time, would this cause big_field to be stored in memory also?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that big_field is a problem?  Have you benchmarked memory usage?  Can you provide the details on how you were able to prove that this is causing problems?  Can you be specific on what problems this is causing?  Slowness?  Crashes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can force your queries to fetch [only](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#only) the fields that you want, to save memory.